# Is it possible to have these 2 queries in one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select convert(varchar(8), max(checkdate),1) lastcheckdate 
from table 
where status = 'processed' 
and not status in ('delivered', 'scheduled')

Select convert(varchar(8), max(checkdate),1) as nextcheckdate 
from table 
where status = 'scheduled'
and not status in ('delivered', 'processed')
```

What I'm looking for is 1 single row that has `nextcheckdate` and `lastcheckdate`. Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you tell us what the primary key is for the table please?

Comment: The primary key would be company code. A 4 digit code assigned to each company in the db.

Comment: Wouldn't the `nextcheckdate` be the `MIN` of the checkdates with a 'scheduled' status?  just trying to understand the context here...

Comment: You are right. That was a typo. I'm sorry for the mix up. Max would be for last check date and Min for next check date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally, I think the following returns the two values.

```
select convert(varchar(8), max(case when status = 'processed' then checkdate end), 1
              ) as lastcheckdate,
       convert(varchar(8), max(case when status = 'scheduled' then checkdate end), 1
              ) as nextcheckdate
from table;
```

However, your queries are someone non-sensical.  The `where` clause in each case is checking that status has a value (say `'processed'`).  When this is true, the `not` part is always true.

This leads me to suspect that there is some aggregation involved, where you are looking for `processed` on rows with some id that don't have the `delivered` or `scheduled` values.  This is speculation, because there is not enough information in the question to know what you are really looking for.

Comment: Well, my table is really a huge calendar table. It consist of company, checkdate and status. Status is processed meaning the payroll has ran, scheduled meaning it will run or delivered meaning it processed and was marked as delivered. I'm trying to build a companies last checkdate and next checkdate into a query to better help my csr's track their clients. Hopefully that gives you a better idea.

Comment: @user1919939 . . . Your problem seems so far removed from this question that I would suggest that you delete this question and ask another one.  Provide sample data and expected results along with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE clauses are redundant.

```
Select convert(varchar(8), max(checkdate),1) lastcheckdate 
from table 
where status = 'processed' 
and not status in ('delivered', 'scheduled')
```

For any row searched, if status = 'processed', then status is neither 'delivered', nor 'scheduled'.  They are exclusive.

Therefore, start working towards your solution by reducing code.

```
Select convert(varchar(8), max(checkdate),1) lastcheckdate 
from table 
where status = 'processed'

Select convert(varchar(8), max(checkdate),1) as nextcheckdate 
from table 
where status = 'scheduled'
```

Now, look at the select columns.  Notice that the function logic is identical except you are aliasing the columns differently.

Let's make them consistent.

```
Select convert(varchar(8), max(checkdate),1) as next_or_last_check_date 
from table 
where status = 'processed'

Select convert(varchar(8), max(checkdate),1) as next_or_last_check_date 
from table 
where status = 'scheduled'
```

Now the only difference is the two status checks.  We can OR them together to make a single query or use an IN (same difference).

```
Select convert(varchar(8), max(checkdate),1) as next_or_last_check_date 
from table 
where status = 'processed'
   or status = 'scheduled'
```

same thing using in:

```
Select convert(varchar(8), max(checkdate),1) as next_or_last_check_date 
from table 
where status IN ( 'processed', 'scheduled' )
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a row with 2 columns - `nextcheckdate` and `lastcheckdate` - not the max of both.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN status = 'processed' 
            THEN convert(varchar(8), max(checkdate),1) 
    END as lastcheckdate, 

    CASE  WHEN status = 'scheduled' 
            THEN convert(varchar(8), max(checkdate),1) 
    END as nextcheckdate

    FROM table
     WHERE status in ('processed', 'scheduled') GROUP BY status
```

This will return two rows.

not happy with 2 rows? Then do this.

```
    DECLARE @table1 TABLE (lastcheckdate int,nextcheckdate int)
    DECLARE @table2 TABLE (lastcheckdate int,nextcheckdate int)

    DECLARE @lastcheckdate int
    DECLARE @nextcheckdate Int

    INSERT INTO @table1(lastcheckdate ,nextcheckdate)
            SELECT 
            CASE WHEN status = 'processed' 
                    THEN convert(varchar(8), max(checkdate),1) 
            END as lastcheckdate, 
            CASE  WHEN status = 'scheduled' 
                    THEN convert(varchar(8), max(checkdate),1) 
            END as nextcheckdate
            FROM table
            WHERE status in ('processed', 'processed') GROUP BY status

    DECLARE test_cur CURSOR
        FOR SELECT lastcheckdate,nextcheckdate FROM @table1

    OPEN test_cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM test_cur INTO @lastcheckdate,@nextcheckdate
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @lastcheckdate IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Table2 (lastcheckdate) VALUES(@lastcheckdate)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE @Table2 SET nextcheckdate = @nextcheckdate
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM test_cur INTO @lastcheckdate,@nextcheckdate
    END
    SELECT * FROM @Table2
```

Answer (score 1):

You gave us too little information to work on but assuming that both your queries are functional and each returns only one row and goal is as you put it *... 1 single row that has `nextcheckdate` and `lastcheckdate`...* you can use `CROSS JOIN` to produce that row

```
SELECT a.lastcheckdate, b.nextcheckdate
  FROM
( 
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), MAX(checkdate), 1) lastcheckdate 
    FROM table 
   WHERE status = 'processed' 
     AND NOT STATUS IN ('delivered', 'scheduled')
) a CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), MAX(checkdate), 1) nextcheckdate 
    FROM table 
   WHERE status = 'scheduled'
     AND NOT STATUS IN ('delivered', 'processed')
) b
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18126)** demo

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select x.customer_id,x.customer_name,
(Select  max(checkdate)
from table 
where status = 'processed' and customer_id = x.customer_id) Lastcheckdate,
(Select max(checkdate) from table 
where status = 'scheduled' and customer_id = x.customer_id) nextcheckdate 
from table x where and not x.status in ('delivered', 'scheduled')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  case when status = 'processed' then convert(varchar(8),checkdate) else null end as lastcheckddate
 ,case when status = 'scheduled' then convert(varchar(8),checkdate) else null end as nextcheckddate
from
  table
where (status = 'processed' and status not in ('delivered', 'scheduled'))
   or (status = 'scheduled' and status not in ('delivered', 'processed'))
```